# Move files into separate directories based on grouping defined in a CSV file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, csv, mv

RELATED: [Move all files with matching prefixes to folder based on a csv list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443125/move-all-files-with-matching-prefixes-to-folder-based-on-a-csv-list)

I have a two-column CSV file (comma-separated values), with headers:

```
"id","group"
"F1256","old"
"E51651","new"
"X56369","new"
"G5481369","old"
"54564564T","old"
"544-5F5","new"
"1298FFF","old"
"JKL-wew_w","new"
```

And I have these files in a single directory:

```
2014-12-15_T921_F1256.png
E51651_hf_2018-9-19.jpg
hf_oldX56369_15-10-2014.xml
2018-07_xx54564564T_hfdata.bmp
G5481369oldbackup_2018-01-01.txt
```

I want to use `grep` (or any other similar tool) on these files, and match their filenames against the `id` column of my CSV file. Upon a match (i.e. if `id` is exactly found in the filename), the file has to be moved to the appropriate `group` sub-directory.

Therefore, two folders, `old` and `new` must be created in the current directory and all those files must be moved according to the described condition.

**RESULT**

```
old
├──2014-12-15_T921_F1256.png
├──2018-07_xx54564564T_hfdata.bmp
├──G5481369oldbackup_2018-01-01.txt

new
├──E51651_hf_2018-9-19.jpg
├──hf_oldX56369_15-10-2014.xml
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In order to help you, please post the *exact* input files that you have.

Comment: Nice task, if you can rely on some rules for your file names. Where is your attempt to solve it? Where are you stuck so we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution can be:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 { group[$2]= group[$2]? group[$2] "* *" $1: $1 ;next }
    END { 
        for (x in group) printf( "echo mv *%s* -t %s\n" , group[x], x )
    }' infile.csv| sh
```

Remove `echo` if you were happy with the result.

```
.
├── infile.csv
├── new
│   ├── E51651_hf_2018-9-19.jpg
│   └── hf_oldX56369_15-10-2014.xml
└── old
    ├── 2014-12-15_T921_F1256.png
    ├── 2018-07_xx54564564T_hfdata.bmp
    └── G5481369oldbackup_2018-01-01.txt
```

this will move all files belonging to related directory group at once.
about the `awk` explanation, please look at [my recent answer](/a/466958/72456).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by first sed n xargs

```
 sed -e '
       s/","/* /;s/^"/*/;s/"$//;1d
 '   |  xargs -l sh -c 'mv $1 "$2"'  _
```

Note : all the caveats apply that come with using an xargs pipeline, e. g.  quotes, whitespace, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"
base_dir="$2"
delim=","

while read -r line
do
    id=${line%$delim*}
    group=${line#*$delim}
    mv *"${id}"* "$base_dir//$group"
done < "$input_file"
```

This example process input file which does not contains the definition (first) line, and id, group are without quotation marks

Comment: much better to just `mv *${id}* ...` than to parse ls

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
import csv, os, glob
filenames = []
filedir = 'files'
with open('filelist.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    filelist = list(reader)
filelist.pop(0)

for k, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(filedir + '/*')):
    filenames.append(os.path.basename(filename))

for (id, directory) in filelist:
    matches = [e for e in filenames if id in e]
    for (filename) in matches:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        os.rename(filedir + '/' + filename, directory + '/' + filename)
```